# How can I use iTunes Match but keep my music videos not from iTunes?

Tags: music, itunes-match, itunes

I currently have my iPad set up to utilize iTunes Match for the music on there. But in my iTunes, I've got a fair amount of music videos on there from sources other than iTunes.

Is there any way to allow the iPad to continue to use iTunes Match to manage audio files, but override it to include all (or a playlist) of my music videos?